# Passing spaces to template through with-param in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, code-generation, indentation

I'm trying to transform an XML document into some plain text code output and would like to have proper indentation. I didn't find any good information how this can be achieved I started to experiment a bit.

At the moment I'm trying to get with-param to pass spaces to templates according to the indentation it should use.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
  <xsl:with-param name="indent">  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Only one problem...the spaces are not passed if the param only contains spaces! Having something else like a character one can pass both leading and trailing spaces, but as soon as I pass only spaces it is changed to empty string.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
  <xsl:with-param name="indent">  a </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Is this expected behavior?

I'm using `xsltproc` on Linux to run the transform.

Let me know what more information I can provide. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having your string as the text node of with `<xsl:with-param>` element, pass it as the `select` attribute.

For example, the following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- With whitespace only. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select=" '   ' "/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <!-- Carriage return. -->    
    <xsl:text>&#xd;</xsl:text>

    <!-- With leading and trailing whitespace. -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="foo">
      <xsl:with-param name="indent" select=" '  b  ' "/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>

    <xsl:text>$</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent"/>
    <xsl:text>$</xsl:text>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input XML:

```
<foo>
  Bar
</foo>
```

produces the following output:

```
$   $
$  b  $
```

Comment: Thanks the the nice example!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use `<xsl:with-param name="indent" select="'  '"/>`.

If you want to pass the value inside the `xsl:with-param` then you need to use

```
<xsl:with-param name="indent">
  <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
</xsl:with-param>
```

or

```
<xsl:with-param name="indent" xml:space="preserve">  </xsl:with-param>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! Using xsl:text works, but the second suggestion with xml:space doesn't make any difference. Unclear why not.

Comment: How do I pass the `$indent` value as well as two more spaces inside the `select` attribute?

Comment: Found it myself: `concat('  ', $indent)`